# Setting variable flash[:message] in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `.erb` file that displays the following lines:

```
<% if flash[:message]%>
<p><span class"error"><%= flash[:message] %></p>
<%end%>
```

I would like to set the variable `flash[:message]` in a `.rb` file and am not sure how to do so. For whatever reason symbols in Ruby tend to confuse me a bit. They seem like pointers, but somewhat different.

**File 1:**

```
class HangpersonGame
 attr_accessor :word
 attr_accessor :guesses
 attr_accessor :wrong_guesses 

  # add the necessary class methods, attributes, etc. here
  # to make the tests in spec/hangperson_game_spec.rb pass.
  # Get a word from remote "random word" service
  # def initialize()
  # end

  def initialize(word)
    @word = word 
    @guesses = "" 
    @wrong_guesses = ""
  end

  def guess(letter)
    # make sure the letter is actually a letter
    if letter == nil || !(letter.class == String && letter =~ /^[A-z]$/i)
      raise ArgumentError
    end

    # handle different cases
    letter.downcase!

    # handle repeated guesses
    if @guesses.include?(letter) || @wrong_guesses.include?(letter)
      flash[message] = "You have already used that letter"
      return false
    end

    #handle case where guess is not a letter
    return false if letter.length != 1

    # finally handle check and return true
    if @word.include? letter
      @guesses << letter
    else
      @wrong_guesses << letter
    end
    return true
  end

  def word_with_guesses
    result = ''
    @word.split('').each do |char|
      if @guesses.include? char
        result << char
      else
        result << '-'
      end
    end

    return result
  end

  def check_win_or_lose
    if word_with_guesses.downcase == @word.downcase
      return :win
    elsif @wrong_guesses.length >= 7
      return :lose
    else
      return :play
    end
  end

  # You can test it by running $ bundle exec irb -I. -r app.rb
  # And then in the irb: irb(main):001:0> HangpersonGame.get_random_word
  #  => "cooking"   <-- some random word
  def self.get_random_word
    require 'uri'
    require 'net/http'
    uri = URI('http://watchout4snakes.com/wo4snakes/Random/RandomWord')
    Net::HTTP.new('watchout4snakes.com').start { |http|
      return http.post(uri, "").body
    }
  end

end
```

**File 2:**

```
<h2>Guess a letter</h2>

<% if flash[:message] %>
  <p>
    <span class="error"><%= flash[:message] %></span>
  </p>
<% end %>

<p>
  Wrong Guesses:
  <span class="guesses"><%= @game.wrong_guesses %></span>
</p>

<p>
  Word so far:
  <span class="word"><%= @game.word_with_guesses %></span>
</p>

<form action="/guess" method="post">
  <input type="text" size="1" name="guess" autocomplete="off"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Guess!"/>
</form>

<%= erb :new %>
```

**File 3:**

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require './lib/hangperson_game.rb'

class HangpersonApp < Sinatra::Base

  enable :sessions
  register Sinatra::Flash

  before do
    @game = session[:game] || HangpersonGame.new('')
  end

  after do
    session[:game] = @game 
  end

  # These two routes are good examples of Sinatra syntax
  # to help you with the rest of the assignment
  get '/' do
    redirect '/new'
  end

  get '/new' do
    erb :new
  end

  post '/create' do
    # NOTE: don't change next line - it's needed by autograder!
    word = params[:word] || HangpersonGame.get_random_word
    # NOTE: don't change previous line - it's needed by autograder!

    @game = HangpersonGame.new(word)
    redirect '/show'
  end

  # Use existing methods in HangpersonGame to process a guess.
  # If a guess is repeated, set flash[:message] to "You have already used that letter."
  # If a guess is invalid, set flash[:message] to "Invalid guess."
  post '/guess' do
    letter = params[:guess].to_s[0]
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###

    @game.guess(letter);

    redirect '/show'
  end

  # Everytime a guess is made, we should eventually end up at this route.
  # Use existing methods in HangpersonGame to check if player has
  # won, lost, or neither, and take the appropriate action.
  # Notice that the show.erb template expects to use the instance variables
  # wrong_guesses and word_with_guesses from @game.
  get '/show' do
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    erb :show # You may change/remove this line
  end

  get '/win' do
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    erb :win # You may change/remove this line
  end

  get '/lose' do
    ### YOUR CODE HERE ###
    erb :lose # You may change/remove this line
  end

end
```

Comment: simply write like this `flash[:message] = 'message'` in the .rb. Whats wrong?

Comment: I had tried doing it as such with no positive results. The error message that I would like to display does not filter through to the `.erb`. I am under the impression that I might be missing something simple as I am still new with Ruby

Comment: Provide error and code.

Comment: Well no direct Ruby errors. The code is being tested through cucumber and it's not seeing the error message

Comment: Well if the question is not too your liking you shouldn't have responded. It actually is quite a simple question though. I was asking for the proper way to set such a variable. Shouldn't be that difficult if you're fluent with the language. Your lack luster solution and missing explanation were exactly very good either. Enjoy your day!...and don't comment if you can't be nice and helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged the question as ruby-on-rails, but it is sinatra.
In ruby-on-rails you set the flash message in the controller (it's part of the session). You cannot set it in the model.

I don't know how Sinatra works, but I read it's similar. I found this:

[Flash message in Sinatra](http://roseweixel.github.io/blog/2014/10/28/flash-messages-with-sessions-in-sinatra/)

You can set the flash message in the controller (post '/guess'):

```
result = @game.guess(letter);
if result == REPEATED then
  session[:message] = "You have already used that letter"
elsif result == WRONG
  session[:message] = "Invalid guess"
else
   session[:message] = nil
end
```

This requires you to change the guess method to return different values instead of just true or false.

Then you can set a variable in the controller (get '/show') to be used in the view. I don't know if this is mandatory (or you could use the session[:message] in the view):

```
@message = session[:message]
session[:message] = nil
```

Finally you show the message in the show view

```
<% if @message %>
  <p>
    <span class="error"><%= @message %></span>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I understand everything that you are saying. Though all those changes aren't allowed File 2 as I have it labelled above must remain intact and can't be changed which is where I am running into this dilemma. Would there be a way to pass a String variable with the message from File 1 to File 3? Then set flash[:message] in File 3

Comment: Never mind I just realized that I'll return the message as a string and pass it over from there. Thank you for your help.